# Flip animation using support fragment manager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation

So I am trying to replicate this: https://developer.android.com/training/animation/cardflip.html

But instead of the vanilla `FragmentManger`, I am trying to do this using the support `FragmentManager`.

Here is what I got going:

In order to make it work for support `Fragment`, I made `anim` files instead of `animator` files.

card_flip_left_in.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


 <!-- Before rotating, immediately set the alpha to 0. -->
  <alpha
      android:valueFrom="1.0"
      android:valueTo="0.0"
      android:propertyName="alpha"
      android:duration="0" />

  <!-- Rotate. -->
  <rotate
      android:valueFrom="-180"
      android:valueTo="0"
      android:propertyName="rotationY"
      android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
      android:duration="@integer/card_flip_time_full" />

  <!-- Half-way through the rotation (see startOffset), set the alpha to 1. -->
  <alpha
      android:valueFrom="0.0"
      android:valueTo="1.0"
      android:propertyName="alpha"
      android:startOffset="@integer/card_flip_time_half"
      android:duration="1" />

</set>
```

card_flip_left_out.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <!-- Rotate. -->
  <rotate
      android:valueFrom="0"
      android:valueTo="180"
      android:propertyName="rotationY"
      android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
      android:duration="@integer/card_flip_time_full" />

  <!-- Half-way through the rotation (see startOffset), set the alpha to 0. -->
  <alpha
      android:valueFrom="1.0"
      android:valueTo="0.0"
      android:propertyName="alpha"
      android:startOffset="@integer/card_flip_time_half"
      android:duration="1" />
</set>
```

card_flip_right_in.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <!-- Before rotating, immediately set the alpha to 0. -->
  <alpha
      android:valueFrom="1.0"
      android:valueTo="0.0"
      android:propertyName="alpha"
      android:duration="0" />

  <!-- Rotate. -->
  <rotate
      android:valueFrom="180"
      android:valueTo="0"
      android:propertyName="rotationY"
      android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
      android:duration="@integer/card_flip_time_full" />

  <!-- Half-way through the rotation (see startOffset), set the alpha to 1. -->
  <alpha
      android:valueFrom="0.0"
      android:valueTo="1.0"
      android:propertyName="alpha"
      android:startOffset="@integer/card_flip_time_half"
      android:duration="1" />
</set>
```

card_flip_right_out.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <!-- Rotate. -->
  <rotate
      android:valueFrom="0"
      android:valueTo="-180"
      android:propertyName="rotationY"
      android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
      android:duration="@integer/card_flip_time_full" />

  <!-- Half-way through the rotation (see startOffset), set the alpha to 0. -->
  <alpha
      android:valueFrom="1.0"
      android:valueTo="0.0"
      android:propertyName="alpha"
      android:startOffset="@integer/card_flip_time_half"
      android:duration="1" />
</set>
```

and finally here is my code for doing the transition:

```
private void flipFragment(Fragment fragment, String tag){
    // if we are showing the back, just pop the back stack
    if(showingBack){
      getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
      showingBack = false;
      return;
    }

    // otherwise flip it
    showingBack = true;
    getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .setCustomAnimations(
            R.anim.card_flip_right_in,
            R.anim.card_flip_right_out,
            R.anim.card_flip_left_in,
            R.anim.card_flip_left_out)
        .replace(getFragmentViewId(), fragment, tag)
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .commit();

  }
```

Everything is working except for the animation.

**EDIT:**
Using the fade animations works just fine:

```
.setCustomAnimations(
        android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out,
        android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your animations aren't working because you aren't using the correct attributes. You'll need to replace `valueFrom` and `valueTo` with the corresponding attrs for your [tween animations](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#Tween).

**Alpha**

`valueFrom` becomes `fromAlpha`

`valueTo` becomes `toAlpha`

**Rotation**

`valueFrom` becomes `fromDegrees`

`valueTo` becomes `toDegrees`

You'll also need to add `pivotX` and `pivotY` attrs.

**Rotation y**

`pivotX="50%"`

`pivotY="0%"`

Comment: ah i see, makes sense. but i am not able to rotate it in 3D, this only rotates in 2d. is it possible to rotate in 3d with tween animations?

Comment: No sree bob. You should try googling some things like "3d animation support fragments" or "card flip animation support fragments".

Comment: that's a shame. i did but all the results point to using non support fragments